# How to read CSV files in sub folder which created today only

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

1.I have a root location(\Wna\sv_prod_01\USERS\Results\thorn-prod) at this location there are 500 folders in which 20 folder created today only and every  folder name start with word PREBATCH.

2.my concern is that how to count csv from 20 folder which start with name PREBATCH

this is what i tried:

```
            DateTime today = DateTime.Now.Date;
            var directoryInfo = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(@"\\\\\Wna001\sv_prod_01\USERS\Results\thorn-prod\");
            int directoryCount = directoryInfo.GetDirectories().Where(x => x.CreationTime.Date == today || x.LastWriteTime == today).Count();====this code is used to count the file which generated today only 

            string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(@"\\\\\Wna001\sv_prod_01\USERS\Results\thorn-prod\", "*PREBATCH*"); ====this code is used to read the folder which start with word PREBATCH

            foreach (string dir in dirs)
            {
                int directoryCount1 = Directory.GetFiles("*.csv");
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SearchOption.AllDirectories` option to look inside all directory for the folder,

Change code like this,

```
    int count = 0;

    string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(@"\\\\\Wna001\sv_prod_01\USERS\Results\thorn-prod\", "*PREBATCH*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    foreach (string dir in dirs)
    {
        var csvFiles = Directory.GetFiles(dir,"*.csv");
        foreach (var file in csvFiles)
            {
                 if(File.GetCreationTime(file) > DateTime.Now.Date)
                 {
                     count ++;
                 }
            }            
    }
```

note: your root dir would be `\\Wna001\sv_prod_01\USERS\Results\`

Comment: by loop i want to count  csv from the  folder which created today only and folder name  start with word PREBATCH .......Hope you are getting my point

Comment: string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(@"\\\\\Wna001\sv_prod_01\USERS\Results\thorn-prod\", "*PREBATCH*", SearchOption.AllDirectories); this code is taking to much time in execution

Comment: if you have large file system than obviously it will take more time

Comment: Is it possible that we can only extract the folder which created today only after that from these folder we can get the csv count

Comment: you need to filter out the folder which are modify from today and lookup file into it